# Why does [RACLifting rac_liftSelector:] print different results between case A and B

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

Why does `[RACLifting rac_liftSelector:]` print different results between case A and B

```
- (void)test
{
RACSignal *signalA = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [subscriber sendNext:@"A"];
    });
    return nil;
}];

RACSignal *signalB = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {


//        {//case A:
//            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//                [subscriber sendNext:@"B"];
//                [subscriber sendNext:@"Another B"];
//                [subscriber sendNext:@"Another Bbbbb"];
//            });
//        }


    {//case B:
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [subscriber sendNext:@"B"];
            [subscriber sendNext:@"Another B"];
            [subscriber sendNext:@"Another Bbbbb"];
        });
    }

    return nil;
}];

[self rac_liftSelector:@selector(doA:withB:) withSignals:signalA, signalB, nil];
}

- (void)doA:(NSString *)A withB:(NSString *)B
{
    NSLog(@"A:%@ and B:%@", A, B);
}
```

As case A and B,there has only one different:the delay time from 1 second change to 3 second. 
But in case A,it NSLog only once as

```
2015-07-16 10:55:28.837 ReactiveCocoa[2563:581353] A:A and B:Another Bbbbb
```

then in case B,it NSLog three times as

```
2015-07-16 10:55:26.819 ReactiveCocoa[2563:581353] A:A and B:B
2015-07-16 10:55:28.836 ReactiveCocoa[2563:581353] A:A and B:Another B
2015-07-16 10:55:28.837 ReactiveCocoa[2563:581353] A:A and B:Another Bbbbb
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rac_liftSelector` works in the same way that `combineLatest` works for `RACSignal`s, it waits until every signal has sent an event before firing.

Because `signalA` doesn't fire for two seconds, and it only sends one event, it's essentially the gatekeeper of `doA:withB:` firing. No matter when `signalA` fires, its single event will never be lost.

`signalB`, on the other hand, sends multiple events. Every event sent before every other `RACSignal` fires (i.e. `signalA`) will be lost except the latest event.

So while `rac_liftSelector` is waiting in "case A:" for `signalA` to fire, the events are not buffered. The first invocation of `doA:withB:` will pass only the latest event from every signal, but will continue passing every event for every signal from then on.